# Converting MMM:SS format into HH:MM:SS

Tags: excel

I have a user input which is given in the form MMM:SS e.g. 103:23 which I want to convert into a normal time format i.e. for the previous example 103:23 would be 01:43:23. Is it possible to do this using an excel formula?

Comment: That depends on how the time is stored in Excel.  Is the "time" a text value that looks like time?  Is it a true time that is formatted `[MM]:SS`?  Each has a different method to do what you want.

Comment: I tried to use 103:23 as a text format but every time I hit enter it defaults to the standard time format. Even if there was a way of entering it in the format 103.22 instead of 103:22 and then convert that into a time that would suffice.

Comment: so you want your users to type in 103:22 and it convert automatically to 01:43:23 in the same cell?

Comment: Calum Can you clarify where user input is coming from and how?

Comment: yes sure, so the input 103.22 would be in A1 and the output would be B1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case I have a limited max time limit so I was able to just write the following based on all of your inputs above. If anyone has any optimization suggestions for the code please feel free to share but this seems to work for the inputs that I have tried.

```
=IF(E3>=420,CONCATENATE("07:",(TEXT((LEFT(E3,3)-420),"00")),":",RIGHT(TEXT(E3,"0.00"),2)),
IF(E3>=360,CONCATENATE("06:",(TEXT((LEFT(E3,3)-360),"00")),":",RIGHT(TEXT(E3,"0.00"),2)),
IF(E3>=300,CONCATENATE("05:",(TEXT((LEFT(E3,3)-300),"00")),":",RIGHT(TEXT(E3,"0.00"),2)),
IF(E3>=240,CONCATENATE("04:",(TEXT((LEFT(E3,3)-240),"00")),":",RIGHT(TEXT(E3,"0.00"),2)),
IF(E3>=180,CONCATENATE("03:",(TEXT((LEFT(E3,3)-180),"00")),":",RIGHT(TEXT(E3,"0.00"),2)),
IF(E3>=120,CONCATENATE("02:",(TEXT((LEFT(E3,3)-120),"00")),":",RIGHT(TEXT(E3,"0.00"),2)),
IF(E3<60,CONCATENATE("00:",(TEXT(LEFT(E3,2),"00")),":",RIGHT(TEXT(E3,"0.00"),2)),
IF(E3>=60,CONCATENATE("01:",(TEXT((LEFT(E3,3)-60),"00")),":",RIGHT(TEXT(E3,"0.00"),2)),
))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula should do it, change A2 to reference the cell then input is in

```
=TIME(0,LEFT(A2,SEARCH(":",A2)-1),MID(A2,SEARCH(":",A2)+1,LEN(A2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done simply by using the formula below where cell C5 is your input time

```
=TEXT(CONVERT(C5,"min","hr"),"hh:mm:ss")
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffQpi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If the input in cell `A1` is text:

- This formula returns a decimal number representing the time:

  ```
  = TIMEVALUE( "00:" & A1 )     'Change the `NumberFormat` to: `"HH:MM:SS"`
  ```
- This formula returns a text representation of the time:

  ```
  =TEXT(TIMEVALUE( "00:" & A1),"HH:MM:SS")
  ```

If the input in cell `A1` is a number, it means that the `NumberFormat` of cell `A1` is `[mm]:ss`:

- This formula returns a decimal number representing the time:

  ```
  = A1                          'Change the `NumberFormat` to: `"HH:MM:SS"`
  ```
- This formula returns a text representation of the time:

  ```
  =TEXT( A1, "HH:MM:SS" )
  ```